# Floats not behaving like floats in a predefined function

Tags: python

I am looking for the precision and recall of a spam filter using predefined functions

when using predefined functions, I cannot get them to return anything other than the value 1.0.

I know that this is not correct because I am supposed to get a precision result of 0.529411764706.

Also, I am using pop because for some reason the first entry of each list is not a number, so I can't use append(int(...

here are the functions:

```
def precision(ref, hyp):
    """Calculates precision.
    Args:
    - ref: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a reference file
    - hyp: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a hypothesis file
    Returns:
    - A floating point number indicating the precision of the hypothesis
    """
    (n, np, ntp) = (len(ref), 0.0, 0.0)
    for i in range(n):
            if bool(hyp[i]):
                    np += 1
                    if bool(ref[i]):
                            ntp += 1
    return ntp/np

def recall(ref, hyp):
    """Calculates recall.
    Args:
    - ref: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a reference file
    - hyp: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a hypothesis file
    Returns:
    - A floating point number indicating the recall rate of the hypothesis
    """
    (n, nt, ntp) = (len(ref), 0.0, 0.0)
    for i in range(n):
            if bool(ref[i]):
                    nt += 1
                    if bool(hyp[i]):
                            ntp += 1
    return ntp/nt
```

Here's my code:

```
import hw10_lib
from hw10_lib import precision
from hw10_lib import recall

actual = []
for line in open("/path/hw10.ref", 'r'):
    actual.append(line.strip().split('\t')[-1])
actual.pop(0)

predicted = []
for line in open("/path/hw10.hyp", 'r'):
    predicted.append(line.strip().split('\t')[-1])
predicted.pop(0)

prec = precision(actual, predicted)
rec = recall(actual, predicted)

print ('Precision: ', prec)
print ('Recall: ', rec)
```

Comment: The `actual` and `predicted` lists are list of strings. You probably wanted to convert them into float list doing: `actualy.append(float(line.strip().split('\t')[-1]))` or something similar.

Comment: What is going on here? There is so much hidden from us. How can we know what precision and recall are doing? Is this your custom code?

Comment: edited to show functions

Comment: as for the reference files: The file
consists of two fields that are separated by a tab space. As specified in the first line of the file, the first
field tells you the name of each email and the second field tells you whether it is a spam or not - 1 if it is a
spam and 0 if it is not a spam.

However there is a line starting these files that appears in my lists, which is not allowing me to convert them to floats or integers

Answer (score 1):

You are treating strings as numbers in your functions. 
Testing bool(aString) will always be true if the string is not empty.

Convert your valid fields to float either before you pass them to your functions, or within the functions when you loop over the values.

```
bool("0") # True
bool("1") # True
```

If everything is always True then 1 / 1 == 1 and 100 / 100 == 1

Also remember to divide floats and not ints, to maintain float precision.

```
    for i in range(n):
        if float(hyp[i]):
            np += 1.0
            if float(ref[i]):
                ntp += 1.0
    return ntp/np
```

You could also just properly append the values to the original list:

```
for line in open("/path/hw10.ref", 'r'):
    try:
        val = float(line.strip().split('\t')[-1])
    except:
        continue
    actual.append(val)
```

Then you will have only valid floats and no need to pop.

Comment: can I make the list entries into floats after I pop the first entry?

Comment: You could just use enumerate() when you loop over the file and skip if i==0 and then append floats to the list. Or you can try to convert the line to float each time and catch the exception and skip it.

Comment: ok I got it, I made new lists. Now what if I wanted to define a function that takes precision and recall scores and 
returns F1-score, i.e. a harmonic mean of the two scores

Comment: Just do whatever math you want in the function but ensure you are passing lists of floats :)

Comment: something like this?
def F1:
        (2*precision*recall)/(precision+recall).....



sorry I'm kinda new to programming :(

Comment: Seems like you got your answer in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855459/harmonic-mean-in-a-python-function). Did this one solve your original question here? If so don't forget to mark it as solved.