# Harmonic mean in a python function?

Tags: python, mean

I have 2 functions that give out precision and recall scores, I need to make a harmonic mean function defined in the same library that uses these two scores. The functions looks like this:

here are the functions:

```
def precision(ref, hyp):
    """Calculates precision.
    Args:
    - ref: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a reference file
    - hyp: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a hypothesis file
    Returns:
    - A floating point number indicating the precision of the hypothesis
    """
    (n, np, ntp) = (len(ref), 0.0, 0.0)
    for i in range(n):
            if bool(hyp[i]):
                    np += 1
                    if bool(ref[i]):
                            ntp += 1
    return ntp/np

def recall(ref, hyp):
    """Calculates recall.
    Args:
    - ref: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a reference file
    - hyp: a list of 0's and 1's extracted from a hypothesis file
    Returns:
    - A floating point number indicating the recall rate of the hypothesis
    """
    (n, nt, ntp) = (len(ref), 0.0, 0.0)
    for i in range(n):
            if bool(ref[i]):
                    nt += 1
                    if bool(hyp[i]):
                            ntp += 1
    return ntp/nt
```

What would the harmonic mean function look like?
All I have is this but I know its not right:

```
def F1(precision, recall):
    (2*precision*recall)/(precision+recall)
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is not right? Might help ..

Comment: when I tried to run the program I got TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: Can you show us how you *use* the F1 function? Seems like the parameters you pass are not correct. In particular, the two parameters of `F1` must be numbers.

Comment: the first 2 functions return the values that will be used in the F1 function, not sure how to label them in the new function as all these functions are to be used in a single program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight change of your `F1` function, and with the same `precision` and `recall` function you defined, I have this working:

```
def F1(precision, recall):
    return (2*precision*recall)/(precision+recall)

r = [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
h = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
p = precision(r, h)
rec = recall(r, h)
f = F1(p, rec)
print f
```

Review especially the use of variables I have. You must compute the result of each function and pass them to the `F1` function.

Comment: hmm I'm getting TypeError: F1() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Answer (score 3):

The following will work with any number of arguments:

```
def hmean(*args):
    return len(args) / sum(1. / val for val in args)
```

To compute the harmonic mean of `precision` and `recall`, use:

```
result = hmean(precision, recall)
```

There are two problems with your function:

1. It fails to return a value.
2. On some versions of Python, it would use integer division for integer arguments, truncating the result.

Comment: sorry, what would the args be? I'm working with floats is that it?

Comment: the first 2 functions return values, how do I incorporate those into my hmean function? I guess thats what I meant to ask in regards to what to put for 'args'

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you found this question and you also need to calculate a **weighted** harmonic mean, you can use the following code:

```
def weighted_harmonic_mean(*tuples):
    """
    :param tuples: [(number, weight), (number, weight), etc...]
    """

    return float(sum(v[1] for v in tuples)) / sum(float(val[1]) / val[0] for val in tuples)
```

Just pass in the tuples of numbers alongside their weights, e.g.:

```
weighted_harmonic_mean(
[100, 1],   # weight 1
[50, 2]    # weight 2
)
# returns 60.0
```

(based on the formula from https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/harmonicaverage.asp)