# Calculating Subcontrary Mean from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list of average water flow values in gallons from a set of 5 garden hoses:

`[6.6, 14, 12.6, 8.8, 11.8]`

I want to calculate the subcontrary/harmonic mean of this list and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855567/9042556) that works:

```
def hmean(args):
    return len(args) / sum(1. / val for val in args)

hose_flows = [6.6, 14, 12.6, 8.8, 11.8]
print(hmean(hose_flows)) # 9.986200495805194
```

However I don't find this very elegant... There surely is a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.6.0 or above you can use [statistics.**harmonic_mean**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.harmonic_mean):

```
>>> import statistics
>>> hose_flows = [6.6, 14, 12.6, 8.8, 11.8]
>>> statistics.harmonic_mean(hose_flows)
9.986200495805194
```

Comment: This is perfect.